# CSS background repeat problem

Tags: css

I've got a background image that I want to extend the length of my page along the left margin.

Here is my css...

```
body, html{
    height:100%;
}
#content{
    background:url(../images/leftBorder.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    height:100%;   
}
```

that has a great result:

[image: good result]

Until the content in my page reaches past the page fold line, at this point if I scroll down I get this:

[image: bad result]

All the content is inside a div with the id of "content".

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `#content` element has a height of 100%, so anything below the fold will not be inside it, but will overflow. You can solve this by using `min-height` instead.

```
#content {
    min-height: 100%;   
}
```

Bear in mind `min-height` is not supported in all browsers. In particular, this will not work in IE6 and below. You can use conditional comments to apply a different style for IE6 that sets the `height` property as you were before, which should actually behave as you expect due to a quirk in its rendering.

Comment: Brilliant!  For some reason I was under the impression min-height didn't work as high as IE 7... is that not the case?

Comment: Jascha: I'm sourcing my information from http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html .

Answer (score 0):

The content div is not expanding like you think it is. In reality, it's only being expanded to the height of it's parent, and so on... so it's max size is determined by the body, html, and the window. Try this:

```
body, html{
    height:100%;
}
body {
    background:url(../images/leftBorder.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
#content{
    height:100%;   
}
```

Or, just

```
body {
    background: url(../images/leftBorder.png) repeat-y;
}
```

Comment: Gah, I'm sure this is a good solution, but there is a reason I'm not doing this.  The body already has a background (just a png of some noise) and the left border actually expands on TOP of the body.

Comment: gotcha. let me find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background: url('../images/leftBorder.png') repeat-y;
}
#noise-wrap {
    background: url('../images/noiseBackground.png') repeat-y;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="noise-wrap"></div>
    <!-- content -->
</body>
```

**Note:** Your 'noise' background will not scroll with the rest of the page.

Comment: I think you want `position: fixed`, not `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use fix the background image, so whenever you scroll down it remains in its place

```
#content{
    background:url(../images/leftBorder.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
}
```

plain and simple